# reuse project ID in google cloud platform project

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Is it possible to delete a google cloud platform project, and after the deletion has completed, make another GCP project with the same ID?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nope. Once you've used a project ID it remains *'reserved'* for ever. [This page](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6158840?hl=en) has a bit of info on this topic. Be sure you're choosing unique & identifiable names the first time around. ;)

Comment: What would you consider unique and identifiable? I've got one as `example-193852`.

Comment: This seems lame. Google should allow re-use after the project is held in abeyance for 30 days after deleting it. Seems like all possible IDs will get used up, and this topic will become more troublesome over time.

Answer (score 2):

Nah, the project-ID will be locked forever no matter it is active or being deleted by users once it has been defined and activated...

[Deleting a project has the following consequences:](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/tutorials/storage#clean-up) "You can't reuse the project ID of a deleted project. If you created a custom project ID that you plan to use in the future, you should delete the resources inside the project instead."