# Site name is unavailable firebase hosting

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I created a site with a specific name under firebase hosting i.e `myapp-zzzzzz`

I then thought of a better name and deleted the site `myapp-zzzzzz` under firebase hosting and created a new one `myapp-yyyyyyyy`.

Then I changed my mind and decided to create a site with original name `myapp-zzzzzz` again , however it seems due to firebase caching site names I now get the error :

> Site name is unavailable. Available: `myapp-zzzzzz-69f55`

I tested this with using random suffixlike so  `myapp-randomSuffix`

Are the site names unavailable for certain duration after deletion?
or are they permanently unavailable?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [reuse project ID in google cloud platform project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42728039/reuse-project-id-in-google-cloud-platform-project)

Comment: Note that Firebase uses GCP projects under the hood. You can [restore a GCP project](https://support.google.com/googleapi/answer/6251787) within 30 days of deleting it.

Comment: The question is referring to site name under hosting not firebase project name

Answer (score 0):

> Deleting a site is a permanent action. If you delete a site, Firebase doesn't maintain records of deployed files or deployment history, and the SITE_ID cannot be reactivated by you or anyone else.
>
> [Delete a secondary site](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/multisites)