# Can you Reuse Cluster ID and Instance ID on AlloyDB?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-alloydb

this is a very simple question. I've created an AlloyDB cluster & instance. However I think I don't need it yet for now. I want to delete the cluster & instance and I wonder is the Cluster ID and Instance ID reusable if I want to use it again after I delete it?

We know that [Project ID in GCP is not usable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42728039/reuse-project-id-in-google-cloud-platform-project), I wonder what about Cluster ID and Instance ID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently we don't hold either post-delete. Immediately after deleting the cluster or the primary instance, you can re-use the IDs.

This is subject to change as AlloyDB is in public preview so things are still shifting leading up to GA. I don't know offhand of any plans to change this behavior though.

Comment: Okay thanks for the answer. I'll delete it for now. Also I would suggest that we can stop AlloyDB without deleting it, because I was afraid if it's always on, I'll get charged even though I don't use it.

Comment: Yup! I've brought that feedback to the product team.